# Understanding the pinout for EC2-3NU

Tags: voltage, power, relay

I have never used a relay before but am now in urgent need for one. The only relay I have on hand is called the EC2-3NU, which is a pretty obscure and undocumented part. I have found datasheets and a pinout for the relay but fail to understand it. I am able to pass DC current through the coil pins but not through the normally open (no) pins (4, and 5) which should be, well, normally open. Is it because I DC does not goes through a relay? Am I misunderstanding the pinout? I am really lost here. Datasheet: https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/5699b9c7dad5da7825ac67f49bc95255.pdf[image: Pin layout][image]

Comment: NO -- normally open (no connection to COM when relay is not energized) .... NC -- normally closed (connected to COM when relay is not energized)  ....... the connections to COM reverse when relay is energized

Comment: what is the coil resistance? what is the minimum coil sustain-voltage? what is minimum coil activation-current? once you can make the relay produce a CLICK, then a path should exit for each of your 2 sets of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to pass DC current through the coil pins but not through the normally open (no) pins (4, and 5) which should be, well, normally open. Is it because I DC does not goes through a relay?

Relays are described like switches. And when a switch is "open", it doesn't conduct current because the connection between its terminals is open. When it's "closed" is when we expect it to conduct current.

The relay will have no trouble conducting DC current if you test the normally closed terminal, or energize the coil before testing the normally open terminal.